# openssl verify -CAfile vs -CApath: Different behaviors?

Tags: openssl, certificate, verify

When using "openssl verify" to verify a certificate chain, I see two different behaviors depending on whether -CAfile or -CApath is specified. With -CAfile, the file must contain all of the certificates in the chain including the self-signed root. With -CApath, the directory need only contain the issuer of the certificate being verified; the root certificate need not be present.

Using -CAfile:

```
$ ls -laR
.:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  3 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:27 . 
drwx------. 62 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 11:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:27 trusted
-rw-r--r--.  1 tomiii tomiii 1753 Aug 10 12:27 untrusted.pem

./trusted:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:27 . 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:27 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomiii tomiii   16 Aug 10 12:27 05751b17.0 -> intermediate.pem
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomiii tomiii    8 Aug 10 12:27 b204d74a.0 -> root.pem
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomiii tomiii 1915 Aug 10 12:26 intermediate.pem
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomiii tomiii 1732 Aug 10 12:26 root.pem
$ openssl verify -CAfile trusted/intermediate.pem untrusted.pem
untrusted.pem: C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 SHA256 Code Signing CA
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
$ openssl verify -CAfile <(cat trusted/*) untrusted.pem
untrusted.pem: OK
```

Using -CApath:

```
$ rm trusted/b204d74a.0 trusted/root.pem 
$ ls -laR
.:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  3 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:27 . 
drwx------. 62 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 11:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:29 trusted
-rw-r--r--.  1 tomiii tomiii 1753 Aug 10 12:27 untrusted.pem

./trusted:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:29 . 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomiii tomiii 4096 Aug 10 12:27 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomiii tomiii   16 Aug 10 12:27 05751b17.0 -> intermediate.pem
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomiii tomiii 1915 Aug 10 12:26 intermediate.pem
$ openssl verify -CApath trusted untrusted.pem 
untrusted.pem: OK
```

I cannot find anything in the OpenSSL documentation that explains why -CApath trusts the intermediate certificate by itself while -CAfile does have this same trust and requires the root certificate in order to verify the chain. Why the difference?

Comment: If you give `verify` one of `-CAfile -CApath` but not the other (and _don't_ specify the `-no-` version on 1.1.0+ only) it **uses the default** for the other. Check the defaults on your system/environment (in the default OPENSSLDIR `openssl version -d` unless envvars `SSL_CERT_{FILE,DIR}` are set) and I bet you'll find the default file has your root but the default path=dir doesn't. (This is true for `s_client` etc also in recent versions, but in older versions other than RedHat there was a bug that didn't use the defaults correctly.)

Comment: PS: especially since Symantec recently got metaphorically 'convicted' by CABF and had to sell to Digicert to avoid a sentence at 'hard labor'. Although CABF doesn't have 'jurisdiction' over codesigning.